# Remove object from a list of arrays if field in object equals a certain value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and within those objects, I have another array. I want to filter the results by the checked value in the drilled-down array.

I have tried map, forEach, splice and I think I am missing something.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": "Parent 1",
        "parents": [
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": "Parent 2",
        "parents": [
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": false
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The results I am trying to get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": "Parent 1",
        "parents": [
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "parent": "Parent 2",
        "parents": [
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            },
            {
                "label": "New Item",
                "editable": true,
                "children": [],
                "checked": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `.map()` and `.filter()` should do the job:

```
const result = array.map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  parents: el.parents.filter((c) => c.checked) 
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was just backwards in my initial attempts. Thanks a lot!